# Why is 'pyo' missing from imp.get_suffixes() list?

Tags: python

The function [imp.get_suffixes()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes) returns a list of tuples describing a particular type of module.

I understand that `pyo` is a *.pyc file that was created while optimizations (-O) was on. So `pyo` should had been considered a separate module different from [PY_COMPILED](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.PY_COMPILED) may be PY_COMPILED_OPTIMIZED?

So, why doesn't [imp.get_suffixes()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes) recognizes `pyo` to be a separate module type?

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this question was asked quite a while ago but it's really a moot point now.

As of Python 3.5, PEP 488 *removed* the `pyo` extension and started using `pyc` for both optimised and unoptimised bytecode files. If you go back to 3.4, you'll see that `pyo` *is* included at that point:

```
SOURCE_SUFFIXES = ['.py']
DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = ['.pyc']
OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = ['.pyo']
```

In 3.5, that changed to:

```
SOURCE_SUFFIXES = ['.py']
BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = ['.pyc']
DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES = BYTECODE_SUFFIXES
```

Those changes in PEP 488, along with the PEP 3147 changes made in 3.2, provide a much more powerful means of handling compiled Python, among them:

- the common extension for compiled bytecode, at any optimisation level;
- a cache sub-directory to keep the `pyc` files from cluttering up your source area;
- interpreter version baked in to the `pyc` file name so that you can have files from different Python versions;
- optimisation level also baked into the `pyc` file name so there's no conflict.
- changes to the module loader to make all this work, ensuring that the correct `pyc` file is generated or loaded.